# Combining Wordpress multiple shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, shortcode

I have created four shortcode snippets to display total woocommerce product count, and the product count for each of my three parent categories.

They work but is there a way to combine the 4 snippets (total, apples, oranges, pears) into a single one that allows a variable in the shortcode to denote which product count so display?

```
// [title-total] shortcode
function total_product_count_shortcode( ) {
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'product' );
    return esc_html($count_posts->publish);
}
add_shortcode( 'title-total', 'total_product_count_shortcode' );

// [title-apples] shortcode
add_shortcode( 'title-apples', function() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 254, // Replace with the parent category ID
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

return esc_html( $query->post_count );
} );

// [title-oranges] shortcode
add_shortcode( 'title-oranges', function() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 256, // Replace with the parent category ID
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

return esc_html( $query->post_count );
} );

// [title-pears] shortcode
add_shortcode( 'title-pears', function() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 214, // Replace with the parent category ID
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

return esc_html( $query->post_count );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. as your three last shortcodes are very similar (just the 'terms' value change), we can merge it in one… Then the following code will embed your 4 shortcodes in one:

```
function custom_multi_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array( 'term' => '' ),
        $atts, 'cmulti'
    );

    // 1 - Total product count
    if ( empty($atts['term']) ):    
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'product' );
        return esc_html($count_posts->publish);

    // 2 to 4 - Apples, Oranges and Pears
    else:
        $query = new WP_Query( array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => (int) $atts['term'], // Replace with the parent category ID
                    'include_children' => true,
                ),
            ),
            'nopaging' => true,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        ) );
        return esc_html( $query->post_count );
    endif;
}
add_shortcode( 'cmulti', 'custom_multi_shortcode' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE (for each of them):**

1. products total count: `[cmulti]`
2. Apples: `[cmulti term='254']`
3. Oranges: `[cmulti term='256']`
4. Pears: `[cmulti term='214']`